# Excel-generated CSV, special characters disappear (ÆØÅ) - PHP

Tags: php, encoding, csv, utf-8

I've got some csv-files that I need to import to our system using php. I live in Norway and we got 3 special characters (æøå and uppercase ÆØÅ). The problem is that the uppercase-versions just disappear from my strings. The lowercase ones are displayed with ?, but when using utf8_encode, I get the correct letters.

I am using the following function to import and read the csv-file. The ÆØÅ-letters are already gone when dumping `$arr`

```
$row = 1;
$arr = array();
if (($handle = fopen($imp['importBreddegave'], "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        $row++;

        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            $arr[$row][$c] = $data[$c];
        }
    }

    fclose($handle);
}
```

I guess I need to specify the character-encoding in some way, but I don't manage to figure out how. By standard, cvs-files are encoded by `WINDOWS-1257` as far as I found out. The rest of my page is encoded with `UTF-8`

Anyone got any neat tricks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ugly hack worked. I had to avoid using `fgetcsv` and `fopen`

```
$arr = array();
$content = iconv('windows-1252', 'utf-8', file_get_contents($imp['importBreddegave']));
$contentArr = explode("\n",$content);
foreach ($contentArr as $kr) {
    $tempArr = explode(";",$kr);
    $arr[] = $tempArr;
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If your page outputs UTF-8 data (or better: states that it outputs UTF-8 through the HTTP header/meta charset), you should make sure the data outputted is UTF-8 as well.
You output data in Windows-1257, though your page states that it is UTF-8, causing the characters not to render correctly.

Convert them to utf8 using either utf8_encode of (even better, because utf8_encode assumes your source charset is ISO-8859-1, which it is not) iconv ( http://php.net/iconv )

Comment: Using `echo  $fc = iconv('windows-1255', 'utf-8', file_get_contents($imp['importBreddegave']));` displays the content correctly, but how do I use iconv with fopen?

Comment: $arr[$row][$c] = $iconv('windows-1251', 'utf-8', data[$c]);

Comment: Does not work, the uppercase-letters are already gone at this point. I think I need to specify this at fopen, but I don't know how.

Comment: take a look at http://be.php.net/fgetcsv under "notes" - this probably is the culprit. Try this, before you execute your current code:

    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'en_US.UTF-8');

Comment: did not work, but I managed to fix it myself. Seems like `fgetcsv` and `fopen` does not work that well with these characters. Wrote my script into using `file_get_contents` and exploding the strings. Not as neat, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

First, to see UTF-8 encoding, add this at the beginning of your page:

`<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'); ?>`

Use encoding with `fopen` and `fgetcsv`:

`$data = array_map("utf8_encode", $data);`

Most important: open the CSV with notepad and save it in a UTF-8 format:

[image]